# encoding int32_t to a byte array

Tags: java, c++, c

I am trying to encode an int32_t to a byte array in C++ then pass it to java by a network socket and decode it back to a java integer which is always 32 bits.

I have succeeded in doing this with a 16 bit integer both with unsigned and signed 16 bit integers using this code:

c++ side

```
void Codex::encodeShortToArray(uint16_t inputShort, unsigned char buffer[],int pos)
{   
    // insure its in network byte order
   inputShort = htons(inputShort);

   // encode the bytes
   buffer[pos+1] = (inputShort >> 8);
   buffer[pos+0] =  inputShort; 
}
```

java side:

```
public static short decodeShortFromArray(byte[] array, int pos)
{
    return (short)
            (
                    (array[pos+0] << 8) 
                +   (array[pos+1] & 0xff)
            );        
}
```

But when I try the same with a 32 bit integer it only works for smaller unsigned numbers. Large numbers or signed numbers return a different value after transmission.

c++ side

```
void Codex::encodeIntToArray(uint32_t inputInt, unsigned char buffer[],int pos)
{   
    // insure its in network byte order
    inputInt = htonl(inputInt);

    // encode the bytes
    buffer[pos+3] =  (inputInt >> 24);
    buffer[pos+2] =  (inputInt >> 16);
    buffer[pos+1] =  (inputInt >> 8);
    buffer[pos+0] =   inputInt;         
}
```

java side:

```
public static int decodeIntFromArray(byte[] array, int pos)
{
    return (int)
            (
                    (array[pos+0] << 24) 
                +   (array[pos+1] << 16)                 
                +   (array[pos+2] << 8) 
                +   (array[pos+3] & 0xff)
            );        
}
```

I assume that for four bytes I need a different operation to get the bytes in the right order, but my grasp of byte operations is limited.

Comment: Assuming that the array of bytes is sent and received in order, it's logically wrong to change the byte order of the integer first, since you're decomposing it into least significant to most significant byte. You would need to convert byte order if you reinterpreted the bytes of the integer as an array. But not when you shift out the bytes.

Comment: @user1908813: Given doing bitwise manipulations on signed integers is a bad idea(C++), how do you deal with encoding signed numbers?

Comment: @dmcr_code: WTF are you talking about he is doing unsigned ints in C++

Comment: @acidzombie24: "WTF"-isn't the way to start a talk I guess. ps. In code yes, but he *mentions* signed numbers in his question

Comment: AFAIK there is no real problem except you may get sign extension without wanting to while right shifting bits. It is perfectly valid to cast an int to unsigned int and do right shifts. Its valid to do left shits and AND, OR or XOR operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you're running into is that bytes are signed in Java, and the `<<` operator promotes arguments to integers.  When you do something like:

```
array[pos] << 24
```

What actually happens is better expressed as:

```
(int)array[pos] << 24
```

If `array[pos]` (unsigned) is greater than 127 (ie has its most significant bit set) then Java will treat it as a negative number, and then you have extra sign bits that get shifted.

The solution is to mask these extra bits out:

```
(array[pos] & 0xFF) << 24
//          ^~~~~~
```

A simple example:  0x8000 (unsigned) is decimal 32768.  So you would expect `0x80 << 8` to give you 32768.  Try running the following Java code:

```
    System.out.println(((byte)0x80) << 8);
    System.out.println(((byte)0x80 & 0xFF) << 8);
```

When you mask out the extra sign bits (the second one) you get the expected answer.

So your decode method should read:

```
public static int decodeIntFromArray(byte[] array, int pos)
{
    return (int)
            (
                    ((array[pos+0] & 0xFF) << 24) 
                +   ((array[pos+1] & 0xFF) << 16)                 
                +   ((array[pos+2] & 0xFF) << 8) 
                +   ((array[pos+3] & 0xFF)
            );        
}
```

Comment: Resolved my problem perfectly. I had read that Java does not support unsigned variables, but didn't know it handled bytes this way. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: To be clear, `buf[pos]` does return a byte, not an int.  However, anytime you perform and operation like `<<` or `&` the byte gets extended to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "network" order to send over the network.  You can just do

```
void Codex::encodeIntToArray(uint32_t inputInt, unsigned char buffer[],int pos) {
    *(uint32_t *)(buffer + pos) = inputInt;
}


public static int decodeIntFromArray(byte[] array, int pos) {
    new ByteBuffer(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt(pos);
}
```

Comment: But you really should. Or you'll confuse everyone who has learned that numbers are sent over the network in network byte order.

Comment: Numbers aren't sent over the network in network byte order. The network uses the bytes in headers/protocol in network endian order (big AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its the htonl line. Why are you doing it? Even if it's what you meant you didnt call the java version to get it back in your machine endian order. If you're on little endian machines it will make the order large endian. Its bad practice for you to have a endian converter on a function called encode int to array. You should use an IO stream to do the conversion but IDK why you'd bother unless you need to make big and small endian clients. You didn't convert network order back to machine order on the java side.

Anyways IDK Java well but there could be a problem with signed values. Assuming 0x80 << 24 is int_min (`−2,147,483,648`) then your code should work after removing the htonl line in c++. also you don't need the & 0xFF in java. Try using the int 0x12345678 and see what you get on Java side. Right now I suspect you get 0x78563412 which is 2018915346

Comment: Java is always big endian regardless of machine. Network order is always big endian regardless of machine. C is always host order, which could be several different orders depending on how exotic your device is. So converting to network on the C side is needed but converting to host order on java side is not because Java is always network order.